# How can I set "Azure Pipelines" in Azure Web App settings using terraform and azurerm provider?

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, azure-deployment, azure-container-registry

I created a linux web app on azure using terraform, I would like to run a container inside it and I would like the image to be released via azure pipeline.

This is my app service module in terraform

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "main_app" {
  name                = var.app_service_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id     = var.app_service_plan_id

  site_config {
    ftps_state                              = var.app_service_config.site_config.ftps_state
    http2_enabled                           = var.app_service_config.site_config.http2_enabled
    minimum_tls_version                     = var.app_service_config.site_config.minimum_tls_version
    linux_fx_version                        = var.linux_fx_version
    always_on                               = var.app_service_config.site_config.always_on
    container_registry_use_managed_identity = var.app_service_config.site_config.container_registry_use_managed_identity

    dynamic "application_stack" {
      for_each = var.docker_image_name != null ? [1] : []
      content {
        docker_image_name   = var.docker_image_name
        docker_registry_url = var.docker_registry_url
      }
    }

    app_settings = var.app_settings_map

    identity {
      type = var.identity_type
    }

    tags = {
      environment = var.env
      app         = var.app
    }
  }
}
```

I have set the `docker_image_name` and `docker_registry_url` with the values in my azure container registry, the identity is SystemAssigned and the `container_registry_use_managed_identity` is set to true.

The web app is up and running but I would like the image to be served via pipeline instead of automatically pulling when updating the image.
In other words I should set the point indicated by the arrow in the image:
[Azure Deployment Center Web App settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1aSs.png)

How can I specify this option via terraform using the azurerm provider in azurerm_linux_web_app?